# Could TLM be passed off as routine liturgical abuse in the Diocese of Chicago?

Tags: catholicism, extraordinary-form-of-the-mass, traditionis-custodes

It's pretty clear that the Cardinal from Chicago has an appetite for allowing [random and illicit things](https://www.ncregister.com/news/the-city-of-big-shoulders-and-liturgical-confusion-chicago-faithful-flummoxed-by-inconsistent-liturgy-policy) to happen under the guise of Vatican II.  And he has clamped down on Traditional Latin Mass and *Ad Orientum* Masses because of the *moto proprio* *Traditiones Custodes*.

So, what, other than their conscience, is preventing priests in the Diocese of Chicago from celebrating Mass according to whatever customs they desire (replacing bubbles and a pogo-stick with turifers and the aspergillum)? Why wouldn't celebrating TLM just be considered yet another liturgical abuse allowed as a means to connect with the faithful?

Comment: I don't think this is really a question anyone can answer for as long as Cdl. Cupich doesn't publicly explain himself

Comment: @supportive maybe it could be answered is a broad sweeping fashion? I guess what I'm wonder is - is the TLM technically closer to the by-the-book NO than the by-the-book NO is to the fun-and-fancy-free NO?

Comment: Some might impute plain malice. That is, bishops can be not good people. How else can clownish masses be considered valid, but the Mass of Pope St. Pius V be considered in any way an 'abuse?'